# Need specific UK telephone validation regex matching to below criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

1. The minimum number of characters (excluding spaces) is 11 and the maximum is 13.
2. If the user is entering a phone number starting with something other than '07' or '+447', then the minimum characters is 10 and the maximum is 13.
3. User can enter space.

Following numbers should pass regex

- 07424689253 (11)
- +447424689253 (13)
- 02049533525 (11)
- 0169773355 (10)

I have write this regex but not working. Please help

```
/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/
```

Comment: Did you check this? http://goo.gl/oBlTxF

Comment: Why is `+44 (0) 712 345 6789` invalid?

Comment: yes this is not validating last 2 numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for UK based and only numeric phone number in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518035/regular-expression-for-uk-based-and-only-numeric-phone-number-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^\s*(?:\+44(?:\s*\(\s*0\s*\))?|0)\s*(7(?:\s*\d){9}|(?=\d)[^7](?:\s*\d){8,9})\s*$/
//    ^-------------A------------^    ^-----B-----^ ^-----------C----------^
```

- A is international/domestic code, i.e. `+44`, `0` or `+44 (0)`, consider adding `0044`, `0044 (0)`
- B is mobile phone number, `7` followed by 9 more digits
- C is a landline number, *non-7* followed by 8 or 9 more digits, consider breaking into region groups

Spaces are permitted throughout the whole thing except in the `+44`

There is a capture group which will give you the result of either B or C, depending on the match

---

Examples

```
var re = /^\s*(?:\+44(?:\s*\(\s*0\s*\))?|0)\s*(7(?:\s*\d){9}|(?=\d)[^7](?:\s*\d){8,9})\s*$/;

// Mobile
'+44 (0) 712 345 6789'.match(re); // ["+44 (0) 712 345 6789", "712 345 6789"]
'+44 712 345 6789'.match(re);     // ["+44 712 345 6789",     "712 345 6789"]
'0712 345 6789'.match(re);        // ["0712 345 6789",        "712 345 6789"]

// Landline
'020 4 953 3525'.match(re); // ["020 4 953 3525", "20 4 953 3525"]
'016 977 3355'.match(re);   // ["016 977 3355",   "16 977 3355"]
```

---

Useful *RegExp* patterns used here

- `(?:pattern)` *Non-capture group;* This pattern is a group but not captured seperately
- `(?:\s*\d){9}` Any amount of whitespace followed by a number, 9 times
- `(?=pattern)` *Lookahead;* Look to see if `pattern` would match next, but don't match it
- `(?=\d)[^7]`, If the next character is a digit match the next character if it isn't a `7`

Comment: I've never seen the `(07222) 555555` format written before today so I didn't include it, and you may need to double-check the permitted lengths of landline numbers

Comment: Solid answer with a thorough explanation and examples. This a very nicely written answer, good job :)