# Regex number filtering from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have been looking for way how I could filter data within textarea using regex function for a quite a while now without any success. Below is the regex I want to use to filter UK telephone numbers.

```
(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?
```

*Fiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/qdypo04y/

**I want to achieve the result when the button is clicked it will remove lines which do not meet the regex? Alternatively would remove values which are not UK telephone numbers.**

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is why do you use a textarea to enter a number? Using an input element is more appropriate.

Comment: what is a UK number format? As far as i understand it is just `+44` prefix and 10 digits which could be arbitrary separated by sapces and probably '-'. You seems to assume that numbers started with '0' are also UK numbers. Can you define the formats you are looking for?

Comment: @Serge I assume the regex comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518035/regular-expression-for-uk-based-and-only-numeric-phone-number-in-cakephp)

Comment: @gaetanoM you assumption is correct

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte In actual software its extracted using JSON and inserted into text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart the use of textarea element your issue is:

- how attach click event listener to your button (refer to: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))
- how get the content of textarea and split it into rows (refer to: [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) plus [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join))
- finally how use your regex: refer to [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

An example is:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var txtArea = document.querySelector('textarea[rows="4"][cols="50"]');
    var re = /(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?/;
    var txtArr = txtArea.textContent.split('\n');
    txtArr.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        txtArr[idx] = ele + '  test result is: ' + re.test(ele);
    });
    txtArea.textContent = txtArr.join('\n');
});
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
+447222555555
0800 042 0213
2017/07/14
2017/07/17
2017/07/27
</textarea>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() { 
    var regexp = /(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?/;
    var content=$.trim($("textarea").val()).split('\n');
    var result="";
    for(var i = 0;i < content.length;i++){
        if(regexp.test(content[i])){
            result=result+content[i]+'\n';          
        }
    }
    $("textarea").val(result);
}

</script>
```

used JQuery to take the value from textarea

Comment: I would require JQuery within my software for this, is it possible you could also attach a demo? as I cant get it to work as it displays "]]}"