# How to validate a HTML input for a phone number

Tags: regex, html

**Brief**

Validate a UK Mobile Phone Number field in a HTML Form to take into account the following rules:

1. Phone Number must begin **07**
2. Phone Number must not exceed 11 Digits
3. Spaces are allowed (ignored). I've found that Auto-Fill features sometimes save numbers like 0123456789 or 01234 456 789. I'd rather not cause the inconvenience to the user to reformat their auto-fill input.

**Valid Input Examples**

- 07234567890
- 07234 567 895
- 07 23 45 78 90

**Where I am**

So far, I've only been able to validate my second point using:

`<input id="phonenum" type="tel" pattern="^\d{11}$" required >`

Comment: this is mainly a question of regular expression, I'd use a bit of javascript here as the scenario is more complex, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518035/regular-expression-for-uk-based-and-only-numeric-phone-number-in-cakephp

Comment: [This is validation for India you have manage ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611599/html5-phone-number-validation-with-pattern)

Comment: I wanted to keep the solution fairly streamlined by sticking with regex. @sirnino appears to have what I needed for this brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions you can use the following

```
^(0\W*7\W*(?:\d\W*){9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```
 <input class="form-control" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validatePhoneNumber(){
    var e = document.getElementById('phonenum');
    var phoneNo;
    var firstLetter;
    var secondLetter;
    if(!e){
        return false;
    }

    phoneNo = e.value.replace(/ /g, ''); // remove spaces
    if(phoneNo.length != 11 ){
        return false;
    }

    firstLetter = phoneNo[0];
    secondLetter = phoneNo[1];
    if(firstLetter != "0" || secondLetter != "7"){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```