# Why this is an invalid regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match all UK phone numbers in a string.

The pattern for this is:

`^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$`

But when I try to initiate a new `RegExp` like:

```js
const myRegex = RegExp('^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$','g');
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11))?[s-]?(?|+)44)?[s-]?(?(?:0)?[s-]?(?)?|0)(?:d{2})?[s-]?d{4}[s-]?d{4}|d{3})?[s-]?d{3}[s-]?d{3,4}|d{4})?[s-]?(?:d{5}|d{3}[s-]?d{3})|d{5})?[s-]?d{4,5}|8(?:00[s-]?11[s-]?11|45[s-]?46[s-]?4d))(?:(?:[s-]?(?:x|ext.?s?|#)d+)?)$/: Invalid group

Comment: My question to you is **why?** Why did you decide to use regex for this? This seems overly convoluted. What is your end goal? I think if you provide us with samples of what you want to match and not match we can provide you with a better response/answer. Personally, I don't think the regex is well-formed or should be used exclusively in your case. It seems you have rules that you have added to your regex, just capture those sections and then test them for certain values.

Comment: So the regex may be correct, regex101 does not complain. HOWEVER it is an invalid JavaScript regex due to the unescaped slashes - they are not needed in `/....\..../` instead of a string

Comment: Unlike literal regex, you need to escape properly in the `RegExp` constructor, as strings have escape too - that results in double escaping things, e.g. `\\(`.

Comment: See [Regular expression for UK based and only numeric phone number in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518035/regular-expression-for-uk-based-and-only-numeric-phone-number-in-cakephp)

Comment: @ctwheels: That doesn't answer the question "Why this is an invalid regular expression?" .

Comment: @FelixKling I realized that after I posted it. You beat me to changes and retracted close vote. I'm positive there's a dupe out there though, waiting for Wiktor to find it.

Comment: @ctwheels: There certainly are a lot of questions about string literals + regular expression + escape characters ;)

Comment: JS is backwards compatible with it's dire past.. that is the single quoted string literal interpolates control escapes like `\x20` and `\n` emanating from double quoted C++ strings. Ie. 3 \\\ or 2 \\ evaluate to 1 \. And 1 \ evaluates to 0 if it's not a control code type. So just pretend it's a double quoted string. Which is a somewhat different set of rules for single quoted strings used in most macro lang's.

Answer (score 4):

The error already shows you what the problem is. `\` inside a string literal is the escape character. But escaping a character that doesn't need to be escaped simply "drops" the `\`:

```js
console.log('\(');
```

So the value you are passing to the regular expression engine (and what the error shows you) is:

```
^(?(?...
```

(note: no backslash)

and `(?(` is not a valid character sequence in a regular expression.

You either have to

- escape the escape characters (`"\\("`)
- Use [a regular expression **literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) instead of `RegExp("string")` (`/^.../`).

Comment: I have tried to escape the escape :
new RegExp("^\\\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s ...etc 
But this gives the same error

Comment: You'd have to escape **all** escape characters of course. But using an regular expression literal would be a lot easier.

Comment: Might as well say it uses the same rules as a double quoted string and be done with it.

Comment: @sln: not sure I understand...

Comment: Yeah, you know "\\a" = "\\\a" = '\\a' = '\\\a' and "\n" = '\n' = newline, and "\x20" = '\x20' = space.

Comment: @sln: this is not about single vs double quotes. If you don’t know how escaping in strings works or that there are two levels of escaping (string, regular expression), then saying “it works like in any other string literal” is not helpful.

Comment: You read more than I said...

Comment: You are still using a string literal, this time even without any escaping. Write this:`var myRegex = /.../;` and replace `...` with what you inside the quotation marks in your question. That’s all you need. No `RegExp`. Make sure to read the arrow I linked to.