# pydantic model validation in fastapi

Tags: python, validation, schema, fastapi, pydantic

```
class QueryParams(BaseModel):
    origin: str = Field(...,)
    destination: str = Field(...,)

    @field_validator('origin', 'destination')
    @classmethod
    def different_origin_destination(cls, v: str, info: ValidationInfo) -> str:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            print(v)
            is_same = ""
            print(is_same)
            assert is_same, f'{info.field_name} origin and destination cant be same'
        return v
```

I need pydantic validator in the schema like this for many fields, but for the above i need to compare both, **is this possible in same method**.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) helpful

Comment: @Chris
root_validator deprecated and field_validator not accepting like these params (from link example )

Comment: [Deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#validator-and-root_validator-are-deprecated) - validators you want to apply to items within a generic container should be added by annotating the type argument

Comment: @putta Thanks for letting me know. Options 1 & 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) have now been updated with the relevant examples in Pydantic V2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @model_validator(mode='before')
        @classmethod
        def check_input_data(cls, data: Any) -> Any:
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                if data.get('origin') == data.get('destination'):
                    raise ValueError("Origin and Destination can't be the same.")
            return data
```

The above code is working by using **model_validator**