# How to change pydantic less than or equal validation when inheriting from parent

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following classes:

```py
class ParentClass(BaseModel):
    some_numeric: int = Field(default=10, ge=0, le=100)
    bunch_of_other_fields...
    .
    .
    .

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    # want some_numeric but le=1000
    some_other_fields...
    .
    .
    .
```

Can I override the `some_numeric` field in the child class or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Going from `le=100` to `le=1000` breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle. If you're still interested in overriding the field constraints, consider changing the example so that it does not invalidate SOLID principles.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to re-define only a single constraint so that you wouldn't have to repeat the constraints from the parent?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FieldInfo.merge_field_infos`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.FieldInfo.merge_field_infos).

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo


class ParentClass(BaseModel):
    some_numeric: int = Field(default=10, ge=0, le=100)


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    some_numeric: int = FieldInfo.merge_field_infos(  # type: ignore
        ParentClass.model_fields["some_numeric"],
        Field(le=10),
    )
```