# How to validate model field with pydantic?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I need to validate a "contact number" field of ContactModel but can't find a proper validator.

```
from datetime import date

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, EmailStr, model_validator, field_validator, validator

import re


class ContactModel(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(max_length=15)
    last_name: str = Field(max_length=15)
    email: EmailStr
    contact_number: str
    birth_date: date
    additional_information: str = Field(max_length=250)


    @validator("contact_number")
    def validate_contact_number(self, value):
        """
        123-456-7890
        (123) 456-7890
        123 456 7890
        123.456.7890
        +91 (123) 456-7890
        """
        if not re.match(r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$', value):
            raise ValueError('Invalid contact number')
```

Get the following error:

```
raise PydanticUserError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: `@validator` cannot be applied to instance methods
```

Moreover `@validator` and `@root_validator` seem to be deprecated.

Comment: I think you want to be using `field_validator` for modern Pydantic. Additionally, the error you are seeing is because you tried to decorate a method (but a class method is required).  Add `@classmethod` beneath your `@field_validator` to resolve that.  I suggest you take a look at Pydantic's exceptionally-good documentation and understand the field_validator examples you can find there.  Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you Bill, @field_validator('contact_number') along with @lassmethod works perfectly!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

both `@validator` and `@root_validator` are [deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#validator-and-root_validator-are-deprecated)

You should use `@field_validator`: [latest validation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/)

```py
from datetime import date

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, EmailStr, ValidationInfo, field_validator

import re


class ContactModel(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(max_length=15)
    last_name: str = Field(max_length=15)
    email: EmailStr
    contact_number: str
    birth_date: date
    additional_information: str = Field(max_length=250)


    @field_validator("contact_number")
    def validate_contact_number(cls, value: str, info: ValidationInfo) -> str:
        """
        123-456-7890
        (123) 456-7890
        123 456 7890
        123.456.7890
        +91 (123) 456-7890
        """
        if not re.match(r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$', value):
            raise ValueError('Invalid contact number')
        return value
```

Comment: I still get "cannot be applied to instance methods" when using @field_validator for a class instance like PostgresDsn from pydantic

Comment: The above needs to have `@classmethod` added to it